# How to connect to remote server using mac osx terminal and .ssh file?

Tags: mac-osx, unix

Hey Guys. Just like in the title - do you know how can I connect to remote server using the .ssh file? This file was given to me by a third party company in order to connect to their server via terminal but I forgot the command for it. I know that I was doing it in the past. This file is basically a convert of .ppk file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.ssh isn't a file, it's a folder.
You can connect to a server using a key like this:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/MyPrivateKey.pem user@server
```

Make sure the key has the right permissions (chmod 400).

If you want to see the content of the .ssh-folder, open up Finder, press Shift+Command+G and enter `~/.ssh/`